# How to send product details using ajax call from custom javascript file in magento 1.9?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, magento-1.9

I am learning Magento 1.9 and want to send some of the product details to node server via JQuery ajax call but I am getting following error on console.

> $.ajax is not a function

I am using Magento's default jquery version.

I have added my custom Javascript in skin folder and configured it in page.xml in layout.

What is the recommended and efficient way to do it?

Comment: Are you really sure that you load the JS files in the frontend? Have you checked whether jQuery is loaded in the network tab of your browser's developer tools?

Comment: Yes I have checked it. Jquery is loaded properly.

Comment: Maybe your jQuery using `jQuery` instead of `$`. Check your console by using `jQuery` is it working? if not then may be your `jquery` is not loaded properly

Comment: jQuery is working fine in console.

Comment: Do you probably run your own code **before** jQuery is loaded?